# Multiple day(s) left javascript timer for multiple time zones

Tags: javascript, datetime

What I am trying to accomplish is multiple countdowns with different expiration dates. I have a code snippet from Codepen, I used as a starting point that works for just one countdown. I am also hoping that no matter whether the viewer is in California, or Georgia the expiration will know what the time zone is. I added the suggested getTimezoneOffset() to deal with different time zones. Which causes the countdown to multiply the days remaining to an absurd number that is 50 years in the future. When I remove that, it is fine. So I have not figured out how to implement that suggestion correctly. Through much trial and error I did successfully create a duplicate countdown with a different expiration date. The only thing I don't understand still is how to implement getTimezoneOffset() so that it does not display 17,893 and 17,883 days (50 years worth of days). I am a trial and error javascript modifier. I try stuff until something is no longer broken.

```
var countDownDate = new Date("DEC 27, 2018").getTime();
var countDownDate2 = new Date("DEC 17, 2018").getTime();


// COPY FEED
var data = {
      // OFFER 1
      one:     "Offer One",
      two:     "Free Product",
    three:     "Today Only",
     // OFFER 2
     four:     "Offer Two",
     five:     "Free Pickup",
      six:     "<span id='daysLeft'></span> <span id='plural'></span>",
  seven:     "Expires: Dec. 27, 2018",
    // OFFER 3

    eight:     "Offer  Three",
    nine:     "<span id='daysLeft2'></span> <span id='plural2'></span>",

     ten:    "Expires: Dec. 17, 2018",
};

// LOOP THROUGH KEYS TO GET ALL ELEMENT IDs & CREATE VARIABLES
function bannerFunc() {
    for (key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var value = data[key];
            var key = document.getElementById('" + key + "');
        }
    }

    // ASSIGN OBJECT VALUES TO VARIABLES
      one.innerHTML = data.one;
      two.innerHTML = data.two;
    three.innerHTML = data.three;
     four.innerHTML = data.four;
     five.innerHTML = data.five;
      six.innerHTML = data.six;
    seven.innerHTML = data.seven;
    eight.innerHTML = data.eight;
     nine.innerHTML = data.nine;
     ten.innerHTML = data.ten;

    // DATE CODE


    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
            amountLeft = countDownDate - now,
            days = Math.floor(amountLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1),
            plural = document.getElementById('plural');
            plural.innerHTML = days + ' Days Left';
            if( days < 2 && days > 0 ){
                plural.innerHTML = days + ' Day Left';
            }
            if( days <= 0 ){
                plural.innerHTML = 'Expired';
            }


        var now = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
            amountLeft = countDownDate2 - now,
            days = Math.floor(amountLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1),
            plural = document.getElementById('plural2');
            plural2.innerHTML = days + ' Days Left';
            if( days < 2 && days > 0 ){
                plural2.innerHTML = days + ' Day Left';
            }
            if( days <= 0 ){
                plural2.innerHTML = 'Expired';

 }
    }, 1000);
}
bannerFunc();
```

Comment: Store the target date in UTC time so each user's device will see correct local value when passed to `Date`. It knows what the timezone offset is based on operating system timezone settings

Comment: Your latest edit makes it very difficult to figure out what the question is.  People shouldn't need to read the edit history to understand the question; can you please change the text of this question so that it includes some mention of whatever it is that you're asking?

Comment: Thanks. I made the question much more concise. My two countdowns are displaying different days left till expiration, but somehow multiplying and ending up with 50 years of days left. I changed nothing in the date code, just duplicated it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getTimeZoneOffset` for your date calculations. Then define all your dates as UTC dates. (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp).
[More about JS Dates](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)